# Clear Select Menu Based on Other Select Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a couple of select menus populated with data from a PHP/MySQL script.  If, in the first select menu, a value is selected that is defined in an array, the second menu appears.  If the first select menu is subsequently changed to a value that is not in the array, the second menu will disappear again.  I would also, however, like to clear the selection from the second menu.  I've tried a few things (currently commented out), but cannot seem to make it work.

What am I missing?

[Live page](http://invictusaleworks.com/test/listboxes.php)

HTML:

```
<select name="BeerStyle" tabindex="0" id="BeerStyle" data-native-menu="false" data-corners="false" data-theme="f">        
          <option value="">Select a Style...</option>
          <?php
            //SQL Query
            $query = "SELECT styleID, style FROM style ORDER BY ID ASC";

            //Prepare Query, Bind Parameters, Excute Query
            $STH = $DBH->prepare($query);
            $STH->execute();        

            while($row = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {?>
            <option value="<? echo $row['styleID']?> - <? echo $row['style']?>"><? echo $row['styleID']?> - <? echo $row['style']?></option><?
                  }
            ?>
        </select>
        <p id="pBaseStyle" style="display: none;">
            <select name="BaseStyle" tabindex="0" id="BaseStyle" data-native-menu="false" data-corners="false" data-theme="f">        
              <option value="">Select a Base Style...</option>
              <?php
                //SQL Query
                $query = "SELECT styleID, style FROM style ORDER BY ID ASC";

                //Prepare Query, Bind Parameters, Excute Query
                $STH = $DBH->prepare($query);
                $STH->execute();        

                while($row = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {?>
                <option value="<? echo $row['styleID']?> - <? echo $row['style']?>"><? echo $row['styleID']?> - <? echo $row['style']?></option><?
                      }
                ?>
            </select>
        </p>
```

JS:

```
var ShowBaseStyle = [ "5C - Doppelbock", 
                     "20 - Fruit Beer", 
                     "20A - Fruit Beer", 
                     "21 - Spice/Herb/Vegetable Beer",
                     "21A - Spice, Herb, or Vegetable Beer",
                     "21B - Christmas/Winter Specialty Spiced Beer", 
                     "22B - Other Smoked Beer",
                     "22C - Wood-Aged Beer",
                     "23 - Specialty Beer",
                     "23A - Specialty Beer",
                     "26B - Braggot"];

      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#BeerStyle').change(function() {
          if (jQuery.inArray( $(this).val(), ShowBaseStyle )!==-1) {
            $('#pBaseStyle').show();
          } else {
            $('#pBaseStyle').hide();
            //$("#BaseStyle").empty();
            //$('#BaseStyle')[0].selectedIndex = 0;
            //$("#BaseStyle option:first").attr("selected", true);
            }
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refresh the control when you modify the selected item:

```
$('#BaseStyle').val('').selectmenu('refresh');
```

What happens here is that your entire question is related not to plain HTML/JavaScript but for jQuery Mobile UI. The JMUI adds additional layer of controls so you need to refresh them when you change the underlying plain HTML controls. I suspect that there should be routines for automatic binding but they are not working/configured in this case.

Comment: I do have the script for this http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/selectmenu-custom-filter/.  Maybe that is affecting it.  Regardless, your solution works great.  Thanks so much!